# Github Action for Windows platform "Windows does not support privileged mode"

Tags: .net, docker, github-actions, windows-container

I have a Windows, .NET Framework 4.8 microservice which I am attempting to dockerize and deploy through Github Actions. (.NET Framework 4.8 hence windows containers is required due to a hard dependency, so Linux is not an option.)

The action is failing on the "buildx" step due to "Windows does not support privileged mode" error. However I can build it manually on my local machine.

The base image is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8
```

The relevant section from the workflow YML script is:

```
  docker-build_my_awesome_microservice:
    name: Builds my_awesome_microservice docker
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Login to GitHub Container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and Push my_awesome_microservice
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          platforms: windows/amd64
          push: true
          tags: ghcr.io/my_awesome_company/my_awesome_microservice:development-latest
```

And the build fails on Github with:

```
Run docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: ghcr.io/my_awesome_company/my_awesome_microservice:development-latest
    load: false
    no-cache: false
    pull: false
    github-token: ***
  env:
    HELM_TIMEOUT: 600s
    HELM_NAMESPACE: apps
    HELM_CHART_VERSION: 0.1.0
    HELM_CHARTS_PAT_TOKEN: ***
Docker info
"C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe" buildx build --iidfile C:/Users/RUNNER~1/AppData/Local/Temp/docker-build-push-O5M3gs/iidfile --tag ghcr.io/my_awesome_company/my_awesome_microservice:development-latest --metadata-file C:/Users/RUNNER~1/AppData/Local/Temp/docker-build-push-O5M3gs/metadata-file --push .
#1 [internal] booting buildkit
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1
#1 pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1 0.2s done
#1 creating container buildx_buildkit_builder-bca52bcd-f172-4d75-b242-502ec5f0071c0 done
#1 ERROR: Error response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode
------
 > [internal] booting buildkit:
------
ERROR: Error response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: Error response from daemon: Windows does not support privileged mode
```

I have searched high and low and failed to find a solution in docs etc.

How can I get this Github Action to successfully build and push a Windows based docker image?

Comment: It's using BuildKit which is not supported for Windows containers. Looks like there's an existing feature request for Windows support on this build-push-action action: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/18.

Comment: Thanks @MattThalman
Can you suggest an alternative action which would work on windows build server?

Comment: So, both are not supported for Windows containers: Privileged and BuildKit. As pointed out, BuildKit has a open request to support Windows containers. As for --privileged, this is not supported on Windows containers and with the Linux community moving away from it, you can expect that it won't be supported. The alternative is to use Host Process containers, but that is containerD feature and only supported on Kubernetes.

Comment: As for an alternative, have you tried Azure Container Registry Tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-overview

Comment: Thanks - this helped me find a solution, posted below.

Answer (score 0):

With help from the comments above, I simply changed the docker build step to use a Windows-compatible action (namely **mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v5**) and this worked:

```
 docker-build_my_awesome_microservice:
    name: Build my_awesome_microservice docker
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: test_my_awesome_microservice
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build and Push my_awesome_microservice
        uses: mr-smithers-excellent/docker-build-push@v5
        with:
          image: my_awesome_microservice
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          platform: windows/amd64
          tags: development-latest
```